# Android Nougat visibility

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a visual problem when I change visibility status:
On show error TextView:

[image: Image1]

On hide error TextView:

[image: Image2]

I need to set text and toggle from not UI thread.

It happens only on **Android 7.0**, on below versions it's look OK.

What I am doing wrong?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/MainLayoutStyle"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="ru.*****.******.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vertical_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="90"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/greenprogress"
            android:id="@+id/batteryProgress" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TitleStyle"
            android:text="123"
            android:id="@+id/CarNumberTxtId" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/ErrorStyle"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/ErrorTxtId" />

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/MainInfoStyle"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <TextView
                style="@style/CounterStyle"
                android:text="0"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/SumCounterTxtId" />
            <TextView
                style="@style/CounterStyle"
                android:text="0"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                android:id="@+id/OnceCounterTxtId" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            style="@style/CounterStyle"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/TempCountersTxtId" />

        <Button
            android:text="Закончить заправку"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/StopBtnId"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/FillingDataId" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
private static void setErrorText(final String txt) {
    hMainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ErrorTxtTV.setText(s);
            if(s == null) {
                if(ErrorTxtTV.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    ErrorTxtTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.d("wLog", "Make INVISIBLE");
                }
            }
            else if(ErrorTxtTV.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                ErrorTxtTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.d("wLog", "Make VISIBLE");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If `s` is string then just check it by `if(TextUtils.isEmpty(s))` instead of `if(s == null) {`

Comment: what do u want? and what is you are getting?

Comment: Log is work OK - so I think if/else work good! In Android <7.0 it`s look OK, but on 7.0 - look bad